# Location of selected vertex

Tags: vertices

I use Blender 2.8 but after selecting a vertex, I can no find the location of the selected vertex?

Is there a place where I can know the x, y and z positions of the vertex?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit mode with vertex selected, **N** key to toggle open the **Properties panel** > **Item tab** > **Transform**, **Vertex**
[image]